# Why don't inbuilt classes in Java have default constructors but arguments need to be passed while creating an object of that class?

Tags: java, constructor, arguments, default-constructor

Why don't inbuilt classes in Java have default constructors but arguments need to be passed while creating an object of that class?

Examples:

```
public final class String
extends Object
implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence

public final class Array
extends Object
```

Comment: Why does it seem necessary to you that they will have a default constructor? A default constructor only makes sense if you can create a usable object with it. Also, `String` does have a default constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned by [RealSkeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191), constructors are useful in cases where a *usable* object can be created without having to pass any arguments to the constructor. It's not all that useful to have an `Integer` without a set value, so it requires an `int` (or a `String` that can be converted to an `int`) to be passed to its constructor.

There are some classes in the java library that do have default constructors, but only when they're likely to be helpful.

To go over the examples you mentioned:

[`String` does have a default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to create an empty string. It's not really useful due to the immutability of strings, but it can still be used when necessary.

[`Array` contains only static methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) and shouldn't be instantiated for any reason.